# Botón que muestre el siguiente archivo en un textBox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, botón

Tengo una función creada la cual devuelve una lista de archivos de una ruta que luego muestro en un textbox mediante un botón de seleccionar archivos. Lo que quiero hacer es otro botón que después de haber seleccionado un archivo txt y haberlo mostrado en el textbox muestre el siguiente txt en la lista, hay alguna librería o algún método de hacerlo. Esta es la función:

```
public string[] obtenerListadoDirectorio(string directorio, string filtro)     
{
    string[] devolver = null;
    string[] listFicheros = null;

    FileInfo[] infFile = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(directorio).GetFiles("*.txt");
    listFicheros = infFile.Select(f => f.Name).ToArray();

    devolver = listFicheros;
    return devolver;
}


public string[] obtenerListadoDirectorio(string directorio)
{
    return obtenerListadoDirectorio(directorio, "*");
}



public string leerFichero (string rutaFichero)
{
    string devolver = "";

    return devolver;
}
```

---

Este es el botón en el que llamo a la función, desde este botón con el openFileDialog abro un directorio en el que están unos archivos .txt y en el que puedo seleccionar que txt quiero abrir y mostrar en un textbox que tengo creado. Lo que quiero hacer ahora es crear otro botón con el que una vez abierto el archivo que haya seleccionado y se haya mostrado en el textbox haga que el textbox pase a mostrar el siguiente txt del directorio.

```
       private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        mailSpam objeto = new mailSpam();
        OpenFileDialog oFD = new OpenFileDialog();
        objeto.obtenerListadoDirectorio(".");
        oFD.Filter = "Documentos de texto (*.txt)|*.txt" + "|Todos los archivos|";
        if (oFD.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = oFD.FileName;
        }
        oFD.FileName = this.textBox1.Text;

        try
        {
            textBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(textBox1.Text);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }


    }
```

Comment: Tras releer varias veces tu pregunta, no termino de entender cual es tu problema. Para empezar, tu método `obtenerListadoDirectorio` tiene un problema ya que no usas `filtro` para nada. Por otro lado, no muestras donde estas llamando al método y donde muestras los resultados en el `TextBox`.Pulsa en [edit] y amplía tu pregunta con esta información y una explicación más específica de que es lo que quieres conseguir.

Comment: Ya la he editado, a ver si se puede entender mejor así.

Comment: Bueno,algo mejor. Resumiendo, quieres un boton para seleccionar un directorio y que en ese momento muestre el contenido del primer txt que ha encontrado,y otro botón que cada vez que se pulse muestre el contenido del siguiente `txt` del directorio seleccionado. Es asi?

Comment: El botón para seleccionar el txt y mostrarlo el en textBox ya lo tengo, necesito uno que al pulsarlo muestre directamente en el textBox el contenido del siguiente txt del directorio seleccionado, lo que has dicho tu vaya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero yo crearía dos propiedades en tu clase, una para almacenar la lista de ficheros y otra el indice del fichero que estamos procesando en esta lista:

```
private string[] listaFicheros {get;set;}
private int indiceFichero {get;set;}
```

Luego yo modificaría el código de tu `button2_Click` para hacer uso de [`FolderBrowserDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx), ya que lo que quieres seleccionar es una carpeta y no un archivo en concreto:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     mailSpam objeto = new mailSpam();    
     using(var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
     {
          DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();
          if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbd.SelectedPath))
          {
               listaFicheros=objeto.obtenerListadoDirectorio(fbd.SelectedPath);
               if (listaFicheros.Length>0)
               {
                    indiceFichero=0;
                    try
                    {
                         textBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(listaFicheros[indiceFichero]);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
               }
          }
     }
```

Por último, el código de tu segundo botón que iría mostrando los demás en secuencia (llamémoslo `button3`):

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    indiceFichero++;
    if (indiceFichero > listaFicheros.Length-1)
    {
        indiceFichero=0;
    }
    try
    {
        textBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(listaFicheros[indiceFichero]);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Este código no está probado así que puede tener algún error, si es así comentámelo.

Comment: En el primer botón prefiero seleccionar los archivos en vez de la carpeta directamente por si necesito abrir uno en concreto pero por lo demás genial. Me funcoina a la perfeccion pero si quisiera mantener el button2 como estaba con el filedialog como gestionaria el button3 para que funcionase?

Comment: @Xabier Pues igual que lo tienes, pero tendrias que guardar en `listaFicheros` el resultado de `obtenerListadoDirectorio` pasándole como parámetro el path del archivo seleccionado.Algo asi:`listaFicheros=objeto.obtenerListadoDirectorio(Path.GetDirectoryName(oFD.FileName));`

Comment: Muchas gracias Pikoh me ha servido de mucho tu ayuda :)